# Python 3.x tkinter: Buttons of specific shapes or Button overlay

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and also rather new to python so I decided to build a "Synthesizer" using tkinter as practice. It's working so far but I can't figure out how to make the keyboard look like an actual piano keyboard, i.e. the black keys are missing. Is there a way to shape buttons in tkinter so i can squeeze the black 
keys in between or perhaps overlay the black key above the white ones?

My code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()

#directory name where sounds are
direc='/Users/nol975/Desktop/tiny-piano00/Piano-'

listofnames=['A4','A5','D#4','D#5','C1','F#5','C3','C4','C5','C6','F#4']

listofkeys=[direc+x+'.wav' for x in listofnames]

def clicked(a):
    (pygame.mixer.Sound(listofkeys[a]).play())

#**********GUI**********


root=Tk()
root.title('My cool synth')

#keyboard
synthframe=Frame(root).pack(side= BOTTOM, anchor='n')

for i in range(len(listofnames)):
    Button(synthframe,text=listofnames[i], command=partial(clicked,i)).pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#Menu bar on top

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=root.destroy)


root.mainloop()
```

also, if I my code so far is sloppy I'd appreciate corrections/feedback

Comment: You don't need `global listofname`. `listofname` is already global, so this is completely useless. Same goes for `listofkeys`.

Comment: For positioning buttons over other buttons, look into the `place` geometry manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't tailor this to your exact example, but I tried modelling piano keys as a grid using the grid I drew in the picture below. Each white key consists of three columns and two rows (blue outline), each black key is two columns and one row (green outline). Of course, the black keys should be placed on top of the white keys.

[image: Pinao keys grid]

Using this model you can place all the keys (the white keys first, then the black keys) on a grid with the sizes as defined and the black keys shifted two rows to the right relative to the white keys. Using `grid()` to put one button (partly) on top of another works perfectly. I defined a list (`[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`) to indicate whether black key should be placed after the white key.

```
import tkinter as tk

def clicked(color, num):
    print(color + ': ' + str(num))

root = tk.Tk()

scales = 3

root.geometry('{}x200'.format(300 * scales))

white_keys = 7 * scales
black = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] * scales

for i in range(white_keys):
    tk.Button(root, bg='white', activebackground='gray87', command=lambda i=i: clicked('White', i)).grid(row=0, column=i*3, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

for i in range(white_keys - 1):
    if black[i]:
        tk.Button(root, bg='black', activebackground='gray12', command=lambda i=i: clicked('Black', i)).grid(row=0, column=(i*3)+2, rowspan=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

for i in range(white_keys * 3):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

for i in range(2):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Using `scales=3`, this gives

[image: Tkinter piano]

There's enough things you could tweak about this, but I actually quite like the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `place` for positioning and `widget.tkraise()` to bring specific buttons to the front.